# How can I 'Parse' { entry.belongsTo } to array with users?

Tags: plugin-development, templating

From my plugin, I know I can use ...

```
craft()->templates->renderObjectTemplate($string, $entry)
```

... to parse, for example, { belongsTo.first.fullName } to the full name of the first user in the belongsTo field.

Now, I need an easy way to parse { belongsTo.find } into an array with all users related to this belongsTo field. Is there an easy way to do this, or should I let my plugin do the work?

**Background information**

My custom notification plugin has a settings field where I can set the 'receivers' of a notification. If an entry has a user field called 'belongsTo', and the setting is { belongsTo.find }, I need all the users related to this field, so I can further process the notification.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the full Twig tag for what you want to do.  Perhaps something like the following (which assumes you have an `email` field you are trying to output for each user and want to separate your emails by a comma):

```
{% for person in object.belongsTo %}{{ person.email }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

`renderObjectTemplate` should parse both the abbreviated syntax with a single curly brace or complete Twig tags.  To take a close look, the abbreviated syntax:

```
{ belongsTo.first.fullName }
```

Is being interpreted by Craft as the following:

```
{{ object.belongsTo.first.fullName }}
```

Comment: Ben, this would be useful if I needed fullName, or title. However, what I need is an array with UserModels, to use further down the road ...

Comment: Not sure I understand the question then @PaulVerheul.  I was assuming the belongsTo field was returning userModels and you were preparing your data to output in your template.  Can you explain why you are using `renderObjectTemplate` and still trying to access the variables it's parsing down the road?  `renderObjectTemplate` renders Twig code, so it can output a Twig tag which is already an array, but it's not going to give you an array back to use later.  Is the array you want already available in your `$entry` variable?